# GNS3 icon do not appear in Applications

Tags: applications

a newbie here.

I installed GNS3 on Freyo using command line.

This to be specific:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gns3/ppa
sudo apt-get install gns3-gui
```

Everything went fine and installed successfully.

But when I tried to launch the program from Applications menu, the icon just was not there.

I can launch it from the terminal using:

```
sudo gns3 start
```

I am not able to right click on the icon and select "Keep in dock" either.

How do I get the launcher icon in the applications menu?

Answer (score 3):

OK so here's what I would do (I'm also a fairly newb):

1. open Scratch text editor and create a new file.
2. Paste the following into that new file:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Version=1.0
   Terminal=false
   Type=Application
   Name=GNS3
   Comment=Description of program- whatever you want
   Exec=gns3 start
   Icon=/path/to/gns3icon
   Categories=
   ```

Note for the `Icon=` line: I usually will save the icon in `/home/your-user-name/.local/share/icons` (After searching online for the icon usually, unless you already know where it is, then just copy it to the `.local/share/icons` folder)

Then save it as `gns3.desktop` in `/home/your-user-name/.local/share/applications/`

It should now be in your Applications menu. Let me know if that works.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the below method and find it simple; install gnome-panel by launching your terminal and enter the below command:

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends gnome-panel
```

after that, enter the following command to add GNS3 into Apps:

```
sudo gnome-desktop-item-edit /usr/share/applications/ --create-new
```

A dialogue box will appear where

1. Select an Icon to use for GNS3.
2. Select the type of launcher, In this case we will be using “Application”.
3. Give the launcher a name, in this case GNS3.
4. This is the command we will run when clicking on the launcher, “gns3” will run GNS3 as root.

Click ok and the launcher will be created.

Note: icon can be downloaded from google [searching gns3 icon for linux; prefer 256x256 res ]